# Facebook share open graph method opens empty pop-up for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use share_open_graph for share video from my app to facebook, it works perfect on descktop, but opens empty page on mobile.
This is a code

```
//Create a new Graph Object
        FB.api(
          'me/objects/video.other',
          'post', {
            'object': {
                'type': 'video.other',
                'url': fileUrl,
                'secure_url': fileUrl,
                'video': fileUrl,
                'video:type' : 'video/mp4',
                'image': imageUrl,
                'title': title,
                'description': shareUrl,
                'video:width': '640',
                'video:height': '390',
                'image:width': '1000',
                'image:height': '610',
            }
          },

          //Call the FB Share dialog - referencing newly created object.
          function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            FB.ui({
                method: 'share_open_graph',
                action_type: 'og.likes',
                display: !this.isMobile ? 'popup' : 'touch',
                mobile_iframe: true,
                action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                  object: response.id,
                  type : 'video/mp4',
                })
            }, function(response) {
                ConfirmationActions.showShareConfirmation(collectionTitle, 'Facebook', !!response.error);
                console.log(response);
              }
            );
          }
        );
```

Actually inspecting this pop-up I mentioned, that there is all needed content for share dialog, but it didn't shown, because #viewport has min-height: 0px;
If I change this height to 550px for ex, I can see the form and content.

`<div id="viewport" class="_2jup" style="min-height: 0px;">`

[This image show empty dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxqky.png)

Comment: Try to add `float` to `#viewport`.

Comment: This viewport generated by facebook, not me. I can not change it. Or may be you can advice, how to do this? Thank you in advance